# Vue.js - Vuex stored javascript model gets converted to object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'am currently running into a problem with Vuex. What I'am trying to do is, store a javascript class (model) in the vuex store. This kinda seems to work, until I'am trying to access the model again. It automatically converts from an class to a plain object.

This is the according vuex module JS file:

```
const state = {
  ownedCoins: []
}

const mutations = {
  ADD_COIN (state, coin) {
    console.log(coin)
    state.ownedCoins.push(coin)
    console.log(state.ownedCoins)
  }
}
const actions = {}

const getters = {
  ownedCoins (state) {
    return state.ownedCoins
  },
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Both console logs in the mutation give me the correct object, but when using the getter the class that was stored turned into an object.

This is the class that should be returned:

```
export default class Coin {
  constructor (name, amount, priceBought) {
    this._priceBought = priceBought
    this._name = name
    this._amount = amount
  }

  get name () {
    return this._name
  }

  set name (value) {
    this._name = value
  }

  get amount () {
    return this._amount
  }

  set amount (value) {
    this._amount = value
  }

  get priceBought () {
    return this._priceBought
  }

  set priceBought (value) {
    this._priceBought = value
  }
}
```

And here I'am committing the object to the store:

```
const coin = new Coin(
  this.formAdd.coin,
  this.formAdd.amount,
  this.formAdd.price
)

this.$store.commit('ADD_COIN', coin)
```

Comment: I assume this is done by Babel. Which preset are you using?

Comment: Using `stage-0`preset

Comment: And also `babel-polyfill`?

Comment: I think You should only store plain javascript objects in Vuex (same as in Redux). Vuex safes all state to the root node 'state'. In this way it is easy to stingefy and initialize the state with json

Comment: Not babel polyfill, but the transform-runtime plugin. 

@StefanvandeVooren Well that would be really pitty, and I have seen it working in a JSFiddle once. So it should be possible.

Comment: I solved it. It didn't seemed to be a problem in the code, but in the Vue Chrome Plugin displaying the wrong store. When accessing the store in the code the correct class returned, when watching the store via the google chrome plugin it just seemed to be an object.

Comment: Yess, but I also notice the original class is decorated with the Vue Observer.  Why do you want to store a class in the state? This will give you problems when saving and re-initialise the vuex state.Wouldn't it be better to store the Coin as plain object and make a extra constructor in the Coin class to convert the plain object back to a Coin class?

Comment: I would go with @StefanvandeVooren 's comment ;) Also close the question as it turned out it's something completely different.